# Почему так не работает(функция get() )?

Tags: c++

Код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int const SZ = 80;

int main()
{
    char buf1[SZ] = "File one", buf2[SZ] = " File two\n";

    ifstream in("file.txt", ios::in | ios::binary);
    if (!in) {
        cout << "Not opened\n";
        system("pause");
        return 1;
    }

    in.get(buf1, SZ - 1);
    cout << buf1;
    cout << "---";
    in.get(buf2, SZ - 1);
    cout << buf2;

    in.close();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Содержимое file.txt:

```
qweFFFFF
rty
```

Какая тут ошибка? Я рассчитывал, что в buf1 запишется `qweFFFFF`, в buf2 `\nrty` но вместо этого, в оба массива, на сколько я понял, в первые же символы пишется `\0` так как вывод программы такой:

```
---Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . . .
```

Comment: Отладчик берите и смотрите что там реально читается.

Comment: @Dim Team Проверьте, возможно ваш файл сохранен в кодировке UNICODE. Потом непонятно, зачем вы его открываете в режиме binary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

функция get читает файл до разделителя, которым по умолчанию является перевод строки. Поэтому, вторая строка не прочитается точно - при чтении первой дойдет до перевода строк, второе чтение проверит этот же перевод строк и успокоится. Вторая строка будет точно пустой.

Как заметили в коментариях, открывать текстовый файл в бинарном режиме в винде (вот это забыли, под линуксом побоку на бинарный режим) чревато различными глюками. Дело в том, что перевод строки в виндовсе кодируется двумя байтами. И в бинарном будет читаться как два байта (\r \n). А в текстовом режиме как один перевод строки (просто \n). Но если в файле смешанные переводы строк - то совсем плохо будет.

Я проверил Ваш код под линуксом и он отлично читает первую строку. После небольшого "фикса", он читает все как "ожидалось".

фикс такой

```
  cout << "---";
+ char n = in.get();
  in.get(buf2, SZ - 1);
```

(это в формате стандартного патча)

Comment: Вы уверены, что бинарный режим ведёт к преобразованию символов?

Comment: как раз в бинарном режиме ничего не преобразовывается. Попоравлю немного фразу.

Comment: Я как раз потому его и включил, что в "Базовом курсе C++, Герберт Шилдт" сказано обратное, а именно, что если не включить ios::binary, возможно преобразование символа перевода строки в \r\n

Comment: Прочитал вашу правку, неужели нет универсального способа чтения, которому всё-равно какие в файле переносы?

Comment: это называется текстовый режим:)

Comment: Спасибо, с вашим патчем и убиранием "ios::binary" всё работает правильно. Выходит, проблема в том, что виндовский "Блокнот" при создании этого файла кодировал перенос строки как CRLF а программа прочитала этот перенос как два символа(в режиме binary)?

Comment: да, блокнот именно так и кодирует. Более того, он "плохо" понимает линуксовые переводы строк (нужно кстати в 10 проверить, а в седьмой точно) - все в одну строку делает. А вот как оно у Вас под виндой работало ... нужно садиться разбираться.

Answer (score 0):

немного упростил ваш код, найдите отличия...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int const SZ = 80;

int main()
{
    char buf1[SZ] = "File one", buf2[SZ] = " File two\n";

    ifstream in("C:\\file.txt", ios::in | ios::binary);
    if (!in) {
        cout << "Not opened\n";
        system("pause");
        return 1;
    }

    in >> buf1; // !
    cout << buf1;
    cout << "---";
    in >> buf2; // !
    cout << buf2;

    in.close();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Зачем? По-моему, я просил помочь разобраться с get()

Comment: просто у вас это похоже на сишный стиль кодирования, а стандарт С++ позволяет избежать много лишнего кода, а то есть избегать много непонятных ошибок

Comment: Оператор ">>" не заменяет get() и её перегруженные варианты. Первая строка могла быть такой: "qwe FFFFF". Вы предлагаете игнорировать её часть после пробела? Отличная идея! Как я сам не додумался... Если есть ошибка, в ней нужно разобраться, а не заменять её более "понятными" вариантами, как иначе развиваться?